# What query is faster: one update with multiple sets or multiple updates with one set?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql

Suppose you have TestTable with columns: field1, field2, ... fieldn.

What query executes faster:

```
UPDATE TestTable set field1 = n1;
```

```
UPDATE TestTable set field2 = n2;
```

...

```
UPDATE TestTable set fieldn = nn;
```

or

```
UPDATE TestTable set 

field1 = n1,

field2 = n2,

....

fieldn = nn;
```

Comment: Normally single statement, you are updating entire table so single one definitely wins.

Comment: Without a `WHERE` the whole table needs to be scanned. In the first version this needs to be done _n_ times. In the second one one time. So the second one should perform better.

Comment: Postgres will create dead rows for the first n-1 updates (which will require vacuuming later) so definitely the single update will be faster.

Comment: At least in Oracle, definitely the single-statement will run faster. Not only due to scanning the data (that is, "on the way in"), but also in saving the results of the work. Oracle generates undo data and redo info, etc., for each UPDATE - and it will do this n times for each row if you do it in n UPDATE statements, so you will also utilize more resources in addition to (much) longer execution time.

Comment: Just by the way, tables have columns not fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question. Try thinking of it this way.

Every set operation takes negligible time 
for every UPDATE = n checks

UPDATE n1 = n 
UPDATE n2 = n
UPDATE n3 = n

So essentially, for n number of updates, you are checking n rows n times, so you are looking at n^2 total checks.
However, if you utilize a SINGLE UPDATE function, you are only checking the n rows ONE time.

Therefore, the second option is significantly better.

Comment: In addition to the number of operations, don't forget the latency between app server and database server!  Milliseconds add up.

Comment: You are exactly right! I was mainly looking at this from a high-level as to not get too technically heavy on OP :)

Answer (score 3):

SQL is set-based. Any time you can work on a set of data in a single operation, you're usually better off.